# Hiding and unhiding math text

Tags: math-mode, packages

Can Latex be used to type a math article containing invisible proofs, each of which becomes visible under the relevant theorem when a button or link is clicked?

Comment: Do you mean a [hyperlink](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks) or something else?

Comment: Thanks very much for some very helpful answers, although I don't think Optical is a very good way of spelling Optional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`fancytooltips`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips); one restriction is that this won't work in most PDF viewers; you need Acrobat Reader:

Your main document will look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[filename=proofs,mouseover,noextratext]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theorem}
\tooltip{Click here to see the proof.}{proofi}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theorem}
\tooltip{Click here to see the proof.}{proofii}

\end{document}
```

the `proofs.tex` document containing the proofs; I placed every proof inside a `tcolorbox`, but, of course, you can use the formatting that best suits your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
  colframe=cyan,
  colback=cyan!30,
  colbacktitle=cyan,
  title=Proof,
  fonttitle=\bfseries
}

\begin{document}

\keytip{proofi}
\begin{tcolorbox}
Some test text for the proof; I will include some math expressions for the test:
\begin{align}
a ( b + c ) &= ab + ac \\
&= ba + ca \\
&= ( b + c) a
\end{align}
\end{tcolorbox}

\clearpage

\keytip{proofii}
\begin{tcolorbox}
Here we add some other expressions for another proof
\[
I_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Here's an image of the output produced by the main document:

[image]

And some images of what you get when your mouse hovers over the text "Click here to see the proof.":

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce the image popup when clicking the blue texts. The texts are clickable with Adobe Reader X using Windows but nothing happens (but the file `proofs.pdf` exists). Maybe, Adobe Acrobat instead of Adobe Reader in needed ... ?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Weird. I used Adobe Reader to view my document and generate the images. If you want, just to test, I could produce the PDF and send it to you, so you can test with my working PDF?

Comment: I just tested on another system. There, it worked. This system has Adobe Reader XI for Windows installed. So, I guess, it's an Adobe Reader version problem. 'X' does not work, 'XI' does. Anyway, thanks for this interesting application :-)

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved with Optional Content Groups (OCG). There are some packages that support OCG. A [CTAN search](http://www.ctan.org/search/?phrase=ocg&ext=false&PORTAL=on&PKG=on&AUTHORS=on&TOPICS=on&max=16) revealed the following packages:

- Package [`ocg-p`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p)
- Package [`ocgx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx)
- Package [`ocgtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgtools)

Example for `ocgx` (randomly choosen):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\begin{document}
\noindent My theorem.
\begin{ocg}{OCG 1}{ocg1}{0}
My proof.
\end{ocg}
\switchocg{ocg1}{\fbox{Toggle proof}}
\end{document}
```

The package requires `pdflatex` (or `lualatex`) and at least *two* LaTeX runs
are needed. (The rerun warning is missing.)

The text "My proof." should be invisible first. After pressing "Toggle proof"
the proof should appear.

However, OCGs are not supported by all PDF viewers.

Comment: The O in OCG is *Optional* not *Optical*.

Comment: @Lumen Thanks, fixed.